# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 overview information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have heard that Microsoft is developing a MVC 2.0 platform for Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone have a good source of information about the upcoming project?
Specifically, an overview of the changes and new features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roadmap was recently published on the CodePlex site:

[ASP.NET MVC Roadmap](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Road%20Map)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Roadmap for MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Road%20Map&referringTitle=Home), including 2.0, at CodePlex.  Also, you may want to follow [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com) -- lot's of info there.

Answer (score 0):

The new strongly typed Html helpers are really nice and work well arlready in the [MVC futures](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22359) library.

Comment: These may not ever be part of System.Web.Mvc, due to performance and feature shortcomings. See Phil's blog for more current thinking:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/02/alternative-to-expressions.aspx

Comment: That's true, but even if this should be the case, I'll gladly continue using them from the current MVCFutures snapshot. After all, these are just strongly typed wrappers around the regular Html helpers, so it's rather unlikely that they will cease to function.

Comment: I don't think they'll cease to function. I just think they may have little to do with the future of MVC, which was, after all, the question.